# Flood Control Does Not Use Correct IP Address

Tags: 9

In settings.php I've done the following:

```
/* Turn on reverse proxy */

$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;

/* Set reverse proxy (load balancer) address */

$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = ['a.b.c.d']; //test-bnc4-web1

/* Enabled trusted headers */

$settings['reverse_proxy_trusted_headers'] = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO | \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED;
```

I'm still not getting the correct client IP in the log when a user fails to login because of an invalid username. It is reporting the second IP address in `$_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR']` where `$_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = 'a.b.c.d, e.f.g.h'` The first IP is the correct one. The second is a switch.

This is important if an IP gets blocked.

Comment: Is the reverse proxy actually setting two IP addresses in X_FORWARDED_FOR?

Comment: I think I'm wrong about there being only one IP in this header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For. I am going to withdraw my answer. It looks like there is a Drupal 7 issue for this however at a glance I can't find one for Drupal 9. The Symfony function getClientIP is aware of this and is supposed to return the leftmost IP https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AgetClientIp/9.0.x so I don't know what is going on with flood control.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this Symfony Framework pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/12283/files), you have to add all intermediate proxies to `reverse_proxy_addresses` for the actual client IP to resolve properly.

The documentation in `settings.php` above `reverse_proxy_addresses` reads:

> In order for this setting to be used you must specify every possible reverse proxy IP address in $settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'].

Comment: You mean X_FORWARDED_FOR can only have one value?